# Does Microsoft Team System support ant?

Tags: ant, tfs

We are using cruisecontrol to build our projects, which are ant files. I'm now checking to use Team System (Microsoft) in the future. Is it possible to use ant scripts in Team System? We have a lot of Flex development (and .NET development) and the scripts to build the Flex side would need to be integrated in Team System.

Comment: You can use CruiseControl with TFS. That is what I did, until I switched to Subversion.

Comment: Lots of development teams using TFS still use CruiseContrl and ant separately. If you're satisfied with ant, perhaps it isn't worth the effort to learn something else. Use the parts of TFS that add to your toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Msbuild is delivered with the .net framework, and was designed to look/act alot like ant.  That said, msbuild is also very extensible in that you can write custom tasks.  I would suspect that writing a build task to call an ant script would not be too difficult to write.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx